# Primes $p$ and $q$ such that $p^3+27pq^2-q^3=2017$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, diophantine-equations

> Find all primes $p$ and $q$ such that
>   $$p^3 + 27pq^2 - q^3 = 2017.$$

I tried using mod $3$ to solve this, however I kept going in circles. I also tried using inequalities, but couldn't  come up with a solution.

Any ideas?

Comment: Mathematica tells me, by the way, that there's exactly one solution over the *integers*, not just the primes.

Comment: To solve the equation for integer $p,q$, Suppose first $27p \ge q$, we get $p^3 \le 2017$ and we only need to check for $1 \le p \le 12$. Now we have to consider the case that $27p < q$...

Comment: Yeah. I tried that, however I with the case that q>27p, I went in circles, and couldn't get much out of it. I think MatheiBoulomenos had a really cool solution in which modulo p will remove the 27pq^2 term

Comment: Deleting this temporarily. Sorry about the inconvenience

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After reducing modulo $27$ we obtain $p^3-q^3 \equiv 19 \pmod{27}$
Using the fact that the only cubes modulo $27$ of elements not divisible by $3$ are [1,8,10,17,19,26](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=k%5E3%20mod%2027%20for%20k%3D1,2,4,5,7,8,10,11,13,14,16,17,19,20,22,23,25,26), we see that $p^3  - q^3 \equiv 19 \pmod{27}$ has no solutions when both $p$ and $q$ are coprime to $3$, thus either $p=3$ or $q=3$.

Suppose $p=3$, then after plugging in and rearranging, we obtain $q^2\cdot(81-q) = 1990$
But note that the RHS $1990=2\cdot5\cdot199$ is square-free, so this is impossible, thus we must have $q=3$.

So after plugging in and rearraging we obtain $p^3+243p=2044$. By trial and error, we find that $p = 7$ is a solution. As the function $f(x) = x^3+243x$ has a strictly positive derivative  $x$, it is strictly monotonously increasing, so we find that this is in fact the only solution.

So the only solution is $p=7, q=3$